# React Native Firebase Microsoft Account Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am attempting to connect my native react project ( android) to allow for Microsoft authentication. I am using this documentation [https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth#microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com)
along with this documentation [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/quickstart-register-app#configure-platform-settings](https://stackoverflow.com) to connect the services. Firebase is creating a redirect URI that I can use but I cannot enter this in the android section of authentication( I can enter this in the mobile and desktop application section but this also does not work). Entra asks me for my packageName ( which I have) and the signature hash ( which I also created). This  generates a redirect URI in Microsoft Entra that is different from the redirect URI created in firebase.

Unfortunately, my issue is that the firebase URI does not match the redirect URI generated by Entra. Is there a way to work around this. Here is the exact error I generate in my app when the button I created in my app is selected.

invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri is not valid. The expected value is a URI which matches a redirect URI registered for this client application.

I have tried to alter the signature hash using 2 different values, I have also attempted to use the redirect URI generated in firebase in the "Mobile and desktop applications" section when selecting add a platform. This is what the entry section looks like in Entra.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClbdV.png)